# ssh routing to subdomains

Tags: nginx, ssh, gitlab, portforwarding

I have a server set up which I ssh into, and I'm running gitlab in a docker container on it and routing the http and https traffic to it through nginx using a subdomain.  That works fine, but I want to do something similar with ssh so that I can use ssh+git. Currently ssh is exposed to the host on 10022, but I don't want to have to open a second ssh port, want I want to do is be able to do this:

```
# To ssh into the server
ssh example.com

# To use ssh+git on gitlab
git clone ssh://git@gitlab.example.com/me/project.git
```

I'm guessing that what I want is some way to inspect the hostname used and forward to the appropriate internal port in a similar way that nginx does it for html trafficw, but I have no idea how to get started.  Is this possible, and if so are there any guides that illustrate how to do it?

Comment: I think the `user@domain` thing by default uses ssh, so try this instead `git clone git@gitlab.example.com:/path/to/repo.git`, notice the `:` between the domain and path

Comment: That was just a typo, the problem is that subdomain is managed by nginx and is on the same host, so `ssh xxx.example.com` is translated to `ssh example.com`.

Comment: ok I understand, so the problem is that port 22 isn't used for ssh and the conenction timesout?

Comment: try `git clone ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:10022/path/to/project.git`

Comment: Using port 10022 works, but I want to use port 22.  Port 22 is already used for connecting to the host server.  So I want to connect using port 22, then forward to 10022 if the subdomain matches

Comment: the domain and subdomain are the same server right? you want ssh-server to listen to both 10022 and 22 ? and handle each differently?

Comment: SSH does not send hostname, so basically `ssh domain.com` and `ssh 1.2.3.4` are absolutly the same for server. The only thing you can do is to proxy all requests for `git` user into container.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thanks, that explains a lot.  How would I go about proxying user requests?

Answer (score -1):

I am in the same situation with [Gitea](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea) and [this](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-with-docker/#sshing-shim-with-authorized_keys) documentation describes in detail what to do:

> Since SSH is running inside the container, SSH needs to be passed through from the host to the container if SSH support is desired. One option would be to run the container SSH on a non-standard port (or moving the host port to a non-standard port). Another option which might be more straightforward is for Gitea users to ssh to a Gitea user on the host which will then relay those connections to the docker.

Comment: Removed my actions here